# how to use GANTracker for long running iOS apps, including background audio

Tags: ios, google-analytics

My App is typically run overnight as a baby monitor, either as foreground app, or with background audio running.

Goals:

1. Track total app startups ie. active user count.
2. Track total usage time in foreground vs background and total session time.
3. Track various page-views if they navigate the settings screens.

As recommended, I start the tracker in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and track my first `ViewController` as my first 'page-view'.  My App might stay on this page then for the next 8 hours...

A couple of issues then appear:

1. When do I call `stopTracker` and what does it do?  I'm hoping that it terminates the tracking session.  But since google kindly hid their code in a static lib, I have no idea what's going on under the covers, and the .h doesn't say much.  First instinct is to put `stopTracker` in `applicationWillResignActive` however, if the user decides to enable background audio my app is still running...
2. Next I read that a session can timeout after 30mins with no new pageviews, or at midnight.  I could set a repeating timer to send the same page-view every 20mins, that should keep my session alive, at least until midnight, but then my page views are going to be much larger? unless it's smart enough to know I'm on the same page with every call.    [google analytics blog](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/08/update-to-sessions-in-google-analytics.html)

[Update: each call seems to be counted as a new pageview, and numbers are thus skewed, so still an issue how to handle this]

1. If my timer above runs past midnight and the session has expired, I'm going to end up with a new session and double the actual active user count?
2. If I do call `stopTracker` in `applicationWillResignActive`, will the next call to track a page-view restart the tracker? or do I need to call `startTrackerWithAccountID` again?
3. If instead I start the tracker in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, I lose the session that might have been running in the background.

[update: this seems to be the best approach so far, but testing is very slow due to time lag on analytics reports, I will report back soon]

PS EasyTracker doesn't seem to handle this any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using a pageview called 'Backgrounded', and when the user has selected no background functionality, then instead the app is calling stopTracker.  I see multiple hits, with an average session of 20mins, but i can multiple pageview by time to see total time for goal 2.  I found two solutions for goal one, events (which were not exposed in easy tracker), and also in my applicationDidBecomeActive (if it's not a restore of backgrounded app) then i track a pageview for AppStarted.  I ended up wrapping the whole thing in a utility class and rolled it into a couple of my apps, so will be interesting too see the results.  If anyone else tries this, you might want to think about using the custom variables too.  I added my app version to this, so I can also monitor how many users are migrating to the latest app releases.